# do not run lemmatize of nltk package

Tags: python, nltk, lemmatization

Hello I Have a code for lemmatization a string in python . code is below

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
print("better :", lemmatizer.lemmatize("better", pos ="a"))
```

but when it compile and run some errors occure

errors is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\s
ite-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 80, in __load
    try: root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, zip_name))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\s
ite-packages\nltk\data.py", line 675, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource ←[93mwordnet←[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  ←[31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')
  ←[0m
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310
\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310
\\share\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310
\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Tor Browser\sort.py", line 3, in <mod
ule>
    print("better :", lemmatizer.lemmatize("better", pos ="a"))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\s
ite-packages\nltk\stem\wordnet.py", line 40, in lemmatize
    lemmas = wordnet._morphy(word, pos)
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\s
ite-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 116, in __getattr__
    self.__load()
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\s
ite-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 81, in __load
    except LookupError: raise e
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\s
ite-packages\nltk\corpus\util.py", line 78, in __load
    root = nltk.data.find('{}/{}'.format(self.subdir, self.__name))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\s
ite-packages\nltk\data.py", line 675, in find
    raise LookupError(resource_not_found)
LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource ←[93mwordnet←[0m not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

  ←[31m>>> import nltk
  >>> nltk.download('wordnet')
  ←[0m
  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310
\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310
\\share\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310
\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data'
**********************************************************************
```

I have already installed the NLTK package with the following command

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

how can i fix it?
I expected the function to work correctly

Comment: When I had that problem once. Restarting my python / kernel somehow fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to

```
import nltk
nltk.download("wordnet")
```

I also had to run this:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('omw-1.4')
```

Can you share the contents of your nltk_data directory (usually it is either C:\Users\yourusername\nltk_data\ or C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data)? Also which version of nltk are you running? (you can get the version by running  nltk.**version**  )

Comment: The result of executing the first command is Package wordnet is already up-to-date! and second command is  Package omw-1.4 is already up-to-date! and content of nltk_data directory is chunkers,corpora,grammars,help,misc,models,sentiment,stemmers,taggers,tokenizers and The nltk version is 3.3.

Comment: @MostafaHeydar I am not sure, but the problem may be that your nltk library is out of date (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/3028)) Can you update your nltk version to a newer one? You can run `pip3 install nltk --upgrade` do update your version of nltk.

Comment: thanks It was fixed